# Habilitar o deshabilitar un input en una tabla de material Design

Tags: javascript, html, angular, material-design

Soy nueva en programación en Angular y necesito llevar a cabo las operaciones de inserción, modificación y borrado en una mat-table de un mat-input, dependiendo de si el valor del elemento tiene ya un valor o no.

Tengo el siguiente código en el html:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="idCodCargAcad">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Clave </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element let i=index;">
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" appearance="none">
           <input matInput  placeholder="Clave" [value]="element.idCodCargAcad"
            [(ngModel)]="element.idCodCargAcad"
            [disabled]="(element.idCodCargAcad !== null)?true:false">
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Pero no me habilita el elemento cuando no es nulo, lo deja siempre deshabilitado. ¿Alguien me podría orientar sobre qué hacer por favor?

Actualmente se visualiza así:
[image: Elemento Clave ya deshabilitado]

Pero necesito que cuando se agregue una fila y el elemento Clave obviamente sea nulo, cambie a estar habilitado.

Los datos se pasan a la tabla de Material-Design en el dataSource y se obtienen de una API. Aquí el código:

```
  // **************** Llamadas a los servicios ****************
  // Función que obtiene las Cargas Académicas

  private fnObtCargAcad(idPrograma: string) { // , arreglo: any
    console.log('Entro a fnObtCargAcad');
    this.svCargAca.fnGetCargAcad(idPrograma).subscribe(data => {
      if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
        this.svSession.setCookie(data.oEncrip.sEncript);
        this.lsCargAcad = data.oLsCargAcaPro;
        this.sOrder = 'iHrsCredMin';
        this.lsCargAcad = this.Exporter.fnSortJSON(this.lsCargAcad, this.sOrder, !this.bReverse);
        // this.fnFiltroCAcad(arreglo);
        this.mDatCargAcad = new MatTableDataSource(this.lsCargAcad);
        console.log(this.mDatCargAcad.data); // obtiene los datos del arreglo
      }
    }, error => {
      alertify.notify(this.Exporter.fnMensajes(error), 5);
    });
  }
```

No sé si requieren más información para ayudarme. La aplicación se está desarrollando en Angular 5.

Comment: de donde viene `element` ?

Comment: Lo obtengo de una Web Api y paso los datos en un dataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendi bien, la logica deberia ser la siguiente

```
 element.idCodCargAcad === null ? true : false
```

Porque disable en caso de ser positivo (`true`) lo deshabilita y en caso de no serlo (`false`) lo activa, lo que sucede es que si no es nulo retornara true y por lo tanto estará deshabilitado.

Answer (score 0):

Usa este código:

```
[disabled]="element.idCodCargAcad">
```

Javascript interpreta una variable con valor como `true`, y una variable `null` o `undefined` como `false`.

Comment: Gracias a ambos, pero no funcionó. Lo que ser requiere es que cuando se llena la mat-table el input del element.idCodCargAcad sea deshabilitado, pero si se agrega una fila a la mat-table éste cambie a habilitado (por eso la necesidad de habilitarlo cuando sea nulo y deshabilitarlo cuando no sea nulo).

Comment: Entiendo. Actualicé la respuesta. Prueba removiendo el  operador de negación `!`.

Comment: "Prueba esto" parece más un comentario que una respuesta. Cuál es la explicación de lo que hace ese código?